# Pass arguments from one HTML page to the other

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am having a problem to get arguments from one HTML page to the other. The case is this: 

I am using PHP and Ajax/jQuery to build this website and the first page is a login form. 
When someone click in the button "login" I am sending a POST request with ajax to a PHP script that will search in the database for this user/password(I am using ajax because if an error occurs I will show a message without reload the page). When the PHP script finishes, it returns the user id to the login page.
How can I go from the login page to another page(e.g. Home) and keep the user id to use there. I know how to resolve this using location.href but I don't want to show the user Id in the URL.

Thank you.

Comment: sessions would be the common approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use sessions:

```
<?php
session_start(); //u have to have this on the top of your page, to be able to use session

$_SESSION["user_id"] = $user_id;

session_destroy(); //u can use this to unset the variables stored in the session. use only   after u are done using with the $_SESSION. 
?>
```

to access the $_SESSION variables(just like post and get):

```
$variable = $_SESSION["user_id"];
```

once u set the session u can use them in any of your page just like a global variable and as long as you put session_start() at the beginning of the page

Answer (score 1):

You should rely on session variables in PHP for this kind of information. You cannot trust the identity that the client would send you, otherwise they could spoof their identity by manipulating the client-side.

Answer (score 0):

Note that there are security concerns with what people think you may be doing with your website/userId. However, to address what you have asked using javascript, you can use [window.sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Storage) to save any information client side until the window is closed. Or if you need persistent information then you can use window.localStorage.